# Fabric Nodejs sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

when I install fabric(fabric-sample) **I use this command** git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git , as same as centos ,then I cd fabric-samples/balance-transfer/  on this folder , **and I execute ./runApp.sh** ,and **I saw my nodejs port 4000 has started (as same as centos)** ,then I execute the **./testApi.sh** ,and I saw some error,any body can help me ? thanks a lot ! the Error picture under the this line.

ubuntu:

the ./testApi.sh
[execute testApi.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb310.png)

and logs:
[instantiate-chaincode1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSbjF.png)

[instantiate-chaincode2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2afGu.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant errors and log output as text. As it is, people searching on the error text won’t be able to find this.

Comment: instantiate-chaincode - Failed to send instantiate transaction and get notifications within the timeout period. undefined
[2017-11-23 11:16:50.408] [ERROR] instantiate-chaincode - Failed to order the transaction. Error code: undefined